# Windows Phone 7.5 handle webrequest redirect

Tags: windows-phone-7, redirect, httpwebrequest

Today i found very strange behavior in WP7.5/7.8

I am implementing authentification, i have to make post request, after that i will be redirected to result page.

In WP8 i am getting result page, after redirect. In WP7.5/7.8 - i am getting redirect result (StatusCode - 302).

```cs
public void MakeRequest() {
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(Consts.Url);
    request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
    request.Method = "POST";

    request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Cookie] = cookie;
    request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(ProcessRequest), request);
}
```

Process response

```cs
private void ProcessRequest(IAsyncResult callbackResult) {
     HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;
     using (HttpWebResponse myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.EndGetResponse(callbackResult)) {

         if (myResponse.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK) {
             RaiseConnectionError(string.Format("Response from server {0}\n{1}", myResponse.StatusCode, myResponse.StatusDescription));
             return;
            }
      }
 }
```

This situation i noticed in backed in current project. When i created the same situation on my backed using ASP.NET MVC,

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Redirect() {
   return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

// index returns simple view
```

it worked for both WP7.5 & 8. It's strange, because backend works fine for iOS and Android.
I saw similar questions, where guys recommends to use custom UserAgent (like normal browser), but it did not work for me.

Comment: Are you able to capture the network traffic on the different requests (using Fiddler or similar) and compare/share them? Or do you have access to the server logs for the different requests? I just tried to reproduce the issue and got OK responses on my calls running on 7.5 & 7.8. It's not an underlying SDK issue but something in your, other, code or the server.